# How to copy properties from one object to another in typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I'm looking for a type safe way to copy properties between objects. I have the code working in javascript and I'm trying to convert it to typescript, however I'm not able to get it working. I'am getting `Type '' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.(2322)`

Can someone please help me understand if it is possible to do what I'm trying to do and what am I missing?

```
enum Kind { PRIMARY, SECONDARY };
enum Size { SMALL, MEDIUM };

type IconProps = { kind: Kind; size: Size; };
type ButtonProps = { id: string; text: string; onClick: () => void; };
type Props = ButtonProps & IconProps;

function iconComponent(props: Partial<IconProps>)  {}
function buttonComponent(props: Partial<ButtonProps>)  {}

const isIconProp = (key: string): key is keyof IconProps =>  /^(kind|size)$/.test(key);
const isButtonProp = (key: string): key is keyof ButtonProps => /^(id|text|onClick)$/.test(key);

function initComponents(props: Partial<Props>) {
  // Default values
  const icon: Partial<IconProps> = {
    kind: Kind.PRIMARY
  };
  const button: Partial<ButtonProps> = {
    id: 'button'
  };

  // How to iterate through keys and assign properties to respective objects?
  Object.keys(props).forEach(key => {
      // Why is this not working?
      if (isIconProp(key)) {
        icon[key] = props[key]
      } 
      
      if (isButtonProp(key)) {
        button[key] = props[key];
      }

      // This works
      if (key === 'kind') {
        icon.kind = props.kind;
      }

      if (key === 'onClick') {
        button.onClick = props.onClick;
      }
  });

  return {
      root: buttonComponent(button), 
      child: [iconComponent(icon)]
    };
}
```

Comment: I don't think you are able to do this in runtime `key is keyof IconProps` as that is not actual javascript. One way you could find if they are icon props or button props is by checking the property names. E.g. is prop kind, or size, then you know its Icon prop.

Comment: @medzz123 Thanks.. As I mentioned, the code works fine in runtime. I'm just looking to statically type check the code with typescript. I have updated the code to make it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with the below approach which seems to be good enough for now. Please comment if there is a better way to do it.

```
const mapTo = <T, S extends T, K extends keyof T>(target: T, source: S, key: K): void => {
    target[key] = source[key];
};


Object.keys(props).forEach(key => {
   if (isIconProp(key)) {
       mapTo(icon, props, key);
   } 
      
   if (isButtonProp(key)) {
       mapTo(button, props, key);
   }
});
```